# Why do the aliens in Aliens "mostly come at night, mostly"?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986, xenomorph

Newt tells Ripley and the marines that the aliens mostly come at night.
Is there any indication of why they are less likely to come during the day? I'm looking for any indications from novelisatons, comics, computer games, other films in the franchise etc or something I may have missed from the film, or any comments in interviews etc. Although I believe they are a differnt continuity I think information on alien behaviour from the Alien vs Predator franchise is admissible.
I have tried to research on wikis but haven't found anyhting about this aspect of their behaviour.

Any evidence that they don't mostly come at night, mostly, and that Newt is therefore mistaken or lying would also be an acceptable answer.

Comment: one possibility is that the xenos, i think being able to hunt without sight or using infrared (or whatever) take advantage of humans' inability to see in the dark. while we take for granted that xenomorphs are practically unbeatable, perhaps over time the colonists learned how to fight them or at least avoid them and the creatures adapted.

Comment: @Donald.McLean: The extra "mostly" in the title is there on purpose: it's quoting a line from the movie.

Comment: @jwodder Why should the title quote from the movie? Does that make it cute or something?

Comment: @jwodder The part that is a quote should be in quotation marks so that people know it's a quote and not just bad grammar.

Comment: No supporting evidence, but I always thought Newt was simply attributing Xenos the typical characteristics monsters have for a child her age, such as appearing at night, for lack of better knowledge on them.

Answer (score 5):

The one book, *Alien: River of Pain*, that describes the Xenomorph infestation on the Acheron colony doesn't actually explain why but it does contain this exchange after the infestation has already claimed several lives including that of Newt's dad:

> Most of the morning had come and gone and there hadn't been an attack from the aliens since the middle of the night.
>
> [...]
>
> "You sure they're not going to attack during the day?" Stam asked.
>
> Dr. Reese frowned. "Not certain, of course. There isn't enough data. But aside from the 'births' of the newborn aliens, their appearances have mostly come at night."
>
> "Mostly," Stam echoed.
>
> (*Alien: River of Pain*, pp.252-253)

In this case, most of the colonists weren't being killed by the Xenos at the time but were abducted to be impregnated by facehuggers. The main attack that wipes out, or abducts, most of the colony including Newt's remaining family occurs within five hours of the exchange between Stam and Dr. Reese, which according to the timestamps in the book is between 2 and 6 PM on Acheron.

As for why the Xenos attack mostly at night, since most of the colonists were hunkered down inside the Hadley's Hope facility it may have been easier for the Xenos to catch them off-guard since, at the time, they were mostly concerned with A. obtaining new hosts and B. protecting their hive from an existing Colonial Marine force already present on Acheron. A character in the novel does mention that some of the colonists blame the lack of coordinated protection efforts for the loss of the others, and it's not until fairly late in the infestation (which starts and ends in roughly 72 hours) that they actively relocate to a single unfortunately-not-so-secure area in the colony where the Xenos have to make a concerted effort to attack.

However, the novel doesn't describe any of the 1-month gap between the fall of Hadley's Hope to the Xenos and the arrival of Ripley and the Marines from Newt's point of view, so we have no way of knowing how often the Xenos came into the colony during that period.